# Interpolate a DataFrame column and sort based on another column in PySpark or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Given the following DataFrame we need to interpolate `my_column` values from the example and use them as separate columns and then sort by the `int_column` values that belong to each `some_id` column in descending order. The example:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
|          some_id   | my_column |      int_column  |
+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
|xx1                 |id_1       |           3      |
|xx1                 |id_2       |           4      |
|xx1                 |id_3       |           5      |
|xx2                 |id_1       |           6      |
|xx2                 |id_2       |           1      |
|xx2                 |id_3       |           3      |
|xx3                 |id_1       |           4      |
|xx3                 |id_2       |           8      |
|xx3                 |id_3       |           9      |
|xx4                 |id_1       |           1      |
+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
|          id_1      | id_2      |      id_3        |
+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
| [xx4, 1]           |[xx2, 1]   |[xx2, 3]          |
| [xx1, 3]           |[xx1, 4]   |[xx1, 5]          |
| [xx3, 4]           |[xx3, 8]   |[xx3, 9]          |
| [xx2, 6]           |null       |null              |
+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

As you can see, for `id_1` the lowest number in `int_column` is 1 right at the end of the DataFrame and it belongs to `xx4` from the `some_id` column, the next value is 3, 4, and 6, each belonging to xx1, xx3, and xx2 respectively.

Any pointers on how to approach this problem? Either PySpark or Pandas can be used.

Code to reproduce the input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'some_id': ['xx1', 'xx1', 'xx1', 'xx2', 'xx2', 'xx2', 'xx3', 'xx3', 'xx3', 'xx4'], \
        'my_column' : ['id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_1'],\
       'int_column' : [3, 4, 5, 6 , 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a helper key , create by using `cumcount` , then we using `groupby` + `apply` (This part just like `pivot`, or you can using `pivot_table` or `crosstab` )

```
df=df.assign(key=df.groupby('my_column').cumcount())
df.groupby(['key','my_column']).apply(lambda x : list(zip(x['some_id'],x['int_column']))[0]).unstack()
Out[378]: 
my_column      id_1      id_2      id_3
key                                    
0          (xx1, 3)  (xx1, 4)  (xx1, 5)
1          (xx2, 6)  (xx2, 1)  (xx2, 3)
2          (xx3, 4)  (xx3, 8)  (xx3, 9)
3          (xx4, 1)      None      None
```

If using `pivot`+`sort_values`

```
df=df.sort_values('int_column').assign(key=df.groupby('my_column').cumcount())
df['Value']=list(zip(df['some_id'],df['int_column']))
s=df.pivot(index='key',columns='my_column',values='Value')
s
Out[397]: 
my_column      id_1      id_2      id_3
key                                    
0          (xx4, 1)  (xx2, 1)  (xx2, 3)
1          (xx1, 3)  (xx1, 4)  (xx1, 5)
2          (xx3, 4)  (xx3, 8)  (xx3, 9)
3          (xx2, 6)      None      None
```

Comment: thanks, how would I also sort the `some_id` values based on values in `int_column` in this workflow?

Comment: @ivan_bilan check the update , you need sort_values first in your original df

Comment: I am getting some strange behaviour, sometimes the results in the end are returned sorted sometimes they are not sorted, any ideas why this could happen? I am using the `.pivot` version.

Comment: @ivan_bilan is your int columns type int?

Comment: no, it's actually `float`, but I don't see any typing being done in the code you shared

Comment: @ivan_bilan would you like share the example which raise the wired behavior ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S  Hi Yoben, i stuck on a interpolation question that i have to fix it by the end of the week ! can you please look at my latest question and give me any tip if it's possible please ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in pyspark.

First define a [`Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) to partition by `my_column` and order by `int_column`. We will define an ordering using [`pyspark.sql.functions.row_number()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) over this partition.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
w = Window.partitionBy("my_column").orderBy("int_column")
df.withColumn("order", f.row_number().over(w)).sort("order").show()
#+-------+---------+----------+-----+
#|some_id|my_column|int_column|order|
#+-------+---------+----------+-----+
#|    xx4|     id_1|         1|    1|
#|    xx2|     id_2|         1|    1|
#|    xx2|     id_3|         3|    1|
#|    xx1|     id_2|         4|    2|
#|    xx1|     id_1|         3|    2|
#|    xx1|     id_3|         5|    2|
#|    xx3|     id_2|         8|    3|
#|    xx3|     id_3|         9|    3|
#|    xx3|     id_1|         4|    3|
#|    xx2|     id_1|         6|    4|
#+-------+---------+----------+-----+
```

Notice that `(xx4, 1)` is in the first row after sorting by `order`, as you explained.

Now you can group by `order` and `pivot` the dataframe on `my_column`. This requires an aggregate function, so I will use [`pyspark.sql.functions.first()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) because I am assuming there is only one `(some_id, int_column)` pair per `order`. Then simply sort by the `order` and drop that column to get the desired output:

```python
df.withColumn("order", f.row_number().over(w))\
    .groupBy("order")\
    .pivot("my_column")\
    .agg(f.first(f.array([f.col("some_id"), f.col("int_column")])))\
    .sort("order")\
    .drop("order")\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+--------+--------+--------+
#|id_1    |id_2    |id_3    |
#+--------+--------+--------+
#|[xx4, 1]|[xx2, 1]|[xx2, 3]|
#|[xx1, 3]|[xx1, 4]|[xx1, 5]|
#|[xx3, 4]|[xx3, 8]|[xx3, 9]|
#|[xx2, 6]|null    |null    |
#+--------+--------+--------+
```